# Can I use delegate in enum? (Swift)

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to use a value from a ViewController in enum. I'm not sure but the only thing I can think of is using a protocol/delegate, which seems like a bad idea...

Right now, the value I want is declared globally, so it works just fine in the code below... but I don't want to declare it globally and would like to declare it in a ViewController.

```swift
import Foundation

enum FIRCollectionReference: String {
    case users
    case chatList
    case chatData
    case templateReply

    func goToLayer() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .chatData:
            return "users/\(myDocId)/chatData"
        case .templateReply:
            return "users/\(myDocId)/chatData"
        default:
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: or you enhance your enums with the id, for example `case templateReply(_ id: String)` and call it via `case .templateReply(let myDocId): return "users/\(myDocId)/chatData"`

Comment: @kamran thanks for the reply! So, if I want to call the enum `.tenplateReply`, how do I input the parameter?

Comment: @zero3nna That sounds easy to call! However, when I tried it I got 4 errors: **'FIRCollectionReference' declares raw type 'String', but does not conform to RawRepresentable and conformance could not be synthesized** at the line `enum FIRCollectionReference: String {`,  **Enum with raw type cannot have cases with arguments** at the line `case templateReply(_ id: String)`, **Pattern cannot match values of type 'FIRCollectionReference'** at the  line `case .templateReply(let myDocId):`,  and **Value of type 'FIRCollectionReference' has no member 'rawValue'** at the line `return self.rawValue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `method` in `enum FIRCollectionReference` that accepts an `Int (myDocId)`, i.e.

```
enum FIRCollectionReference: String {
    case users
    case chatList
    case chatData
    case templateReply

    func goToLayer(_ myDocId: Int) -> String {
        switch self {
        case .chatData:
            return "users/\(myDocId)/chatData"
        case .templateReply:
            return "users/\(myDocId)/chatData"
        default:
            return self.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let reference = FIRCollectionReference.chatData
print(reference.goToLayer(1234))
```

Comment: Oh, so that's how you use a method from enum. Can I just use the reference `print( .chatData.goToLayer(1234) )`? I use FIRCollectionReference a lot, and I'm not sure if I should substitute `var reference` every time I use it... or should I for error handling??

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're trying to say here.